# VS Code automatically move cursor to editor on open from tree view

Tags: visual-studio-code

What I'm looking for seems to be such a basic thing that I'd expect it to be managed by some setting, but I can't find it.

When I click on a file name in the file explorer, the file opens correctly, but the cursor focus remains in the file explorer. I'd like it to automatically put the cursor in the file editor.

Comment: It is surprising there isn't a setting to do that.  You may have to create a macro that adds the command `workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup` to whatever you use to open a file in the explorer.

Comment: A double-click does move focus to the editor (and also opens the file in a non-preview state).